# Getting out of a loop?

Tags: python

I'm taking a programming class in my school, and we just started with python. We are supposed to make our coding print a tic tac toe board using a loop, but I can't figure out how to close the loop and add one last line of coding. Here is what I have so far as my coding:

```
bob = '+----+----+----+'
joe = '|    |    |    |'
index = 0
while index < 3:
    print(bob)
    print(joe)
    print(joe)
    index = index + 1
print(bob)
```

(ps the underscores are tabs in the coding.)
The last line is the line that I am trying to get out of the loop. I have researched it but I everything I find doesn't work, i just get a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". Does anyone know how I can learn how to fix this?

Comment: `break` takes you out of a loop.

Comment: please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I added the code @CrakC, it wasn't there before because I had tried adding an image of it but it didn't work.

Comment: Thank you @Zar, I will try that.

Comment: Thank you @Pynchia for the links.

Comment: @Zar I am confused as to how I'm supposed to use break, could you comment some code that has it in it so I can know where to put it?

Comment: `break` makes a loop stop executing; it doesn't "end" the loop syntactically. You need to indent less to exit the loop, but unless you paste your code here correctly without ...____ nonsense, no one can tell what your code looks like for real.

Comment: You don't need a break for this.  The last line is in the loop because of its indentation.  If you indent it less, so that it lines up with the "while", it will be out of the loop.

Comment: @TomKarzes the last line is in line with the while but I still get the syntax error. Do the three dots mean anything in the coding, because I have noticed l that there is ">>>" and "..." in terminal.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't have any of the dots in your source file.  Use spaces to indent.  When typing it interactively, the interpreter will use different prompts to indicate whether you have an existing scoped construct, but you can ignore that.

Comment: Does your code look like the edit by @CrakC? And you're still getting a syntax error?

Comment: @NateBarbettini that is exactly what my code looks like.

Answer (score 2):

You want it to look like this:

```
bob = '+----+----+----+'
joe = '|    |    |    |'

index = 0

while index < 3:
    print(bob)
    print(joe)
    print(joe)
    index = index + 1

print(bob)
```

The output is:

```
+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
+----+----+----+
```

You can also use range to control the loop.  The following is equivalent:

```
bob = '+----+----+----+'
joe = '|    |    |    |'

for index in range(3):
    print(bob)
    print(joe)
    print(joe)

print(bob)
```

Comment: Thank you this really helps

Comment: How did you get the space between the loop and the last line? What program are you using to type your python code, because I'm using terminal. Does that make a difference?

Comment: You would normally place your code in a file, then run the file.  I suggest finding a good text editor and using it to maintain your source code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more pythonic version you can use to impress your teacher ;)

```
from itertools import cycle
bob = '+----+----+----+'
joe = '|    |    |    |'
board = '\n'.join([r for _, r in zip(range(10), cycle((bob, joe, joe)))])
print(board)
```

produces

```
+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
+----+----+----+
```